# GetVolumePathName on a network share path

Tags: c++, winapi, windows-server-2008

I'm calling [GetVolumePathName](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa364996%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) API on the path for my executable obtained from a call to `GetModuleFileName(NULL,,)` as such:

```
TCHAR buffVolPath[MAX_PATH];
if(GetVolumePathName(buffThisPath, buffVolPath, MAX_PATH))
{
    _tprintf(L"This volume path=%s\n", buffVolPath);
}
```

If I run it from a local path `"D:\Folder\MyProgram.exe"`, I get `"D:\"`.

But if I run it from a redirected folder `"\\SRVR-A\Home\userName\Documents\MyProgram.exe"`, I get `"\\SRVR-A\Home\userName\Documents\MyProgram.exe\"`.

Why am I getting the second result as such?

**EDIT:** It turns out this happens only in the following scenario. When I copy my executable to the `"\\SRVR-A\Home\userName\Documents"` folder and run it immediately afterwards. Then I get that weird result. But if I wait for a little while, the result changes to `"\\SRVR-A\Home\"`. I'm running this test on a Windows 7 Pro, SP1 32-bit client.